# swatches.phtml taking over list.phtml

Tags: swatches, list.phtml

Using the paths inspector, I realize that swatches.phtml is taking over list.phtml in our category pages, even if we have it disabled in Configuration > Settings > Catalog > Configuration Swatches (comes by default in the last Magento version I think).

swatches.phtml seems to be located in /app/design/frontend/THEME/default/template/configurableswatches/catalog/product/list

How is it and how can we get back our list.phtml instead?

One drastic option is copy/paste list.phtml into swatches.phtml but we'd prefer a kinder approach.

Thanks for pointing out ideas, I may be missing something too.

Comment: please use the default RWD list.phtml and swatches.phtml to check if it still happens. If not it's probably some mallformed html in your template files

Comment: Thanks, it was another extension who was (correctly) replacing list.phtml, I got confused with the inspector and blamed to wrong file. I was able to change the proper file to suit our needs.

Comment: Is it solved now?

Comment: Yes, may I answer my own question?

Comment: sure! if you think it's of value to future visiters